# How can I tell find to print a list of files based on the results of running a pipeline on each file?

Tags: linux, command-line, find

I know we can use `find -exec ...` to specify a command to run on each file, and output only those files for which the command succeeds, for example, `find . -exec test -d {} \; -print` will print out all the directories. I will like to give `-exec` a pipeline, and have `find` return files for which the last command of the pipeline returned true.

To be specific, I would like to run `jar -t` on each file, and `grep` the output for a class name. I tried `find . -name \*jar -exec jar -tf {} \|grep -q foo \; -print`, but its returning all the files. How can I change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a command pipe as argument to `-exec` would only work if *find* would utilize a subshell. But *find* just executes **one** command with the an *exec()* function call and all following tokens up to the `;` will be passed as command arguments.

So when in need for nifty shell features, you will have to call the subshell on your own:

```
 $ find . -name '*.jar' -exec sh -c 'jar -tf {} | grep -q foo' \; -print
```